# How do you draw sin, cos and tan with shaders?

Tags: shaders, mathematics

I want to draw sin, cos, tan and other mathematical functions with the shader editor. How do I do this?

[image]

Answer (score 11, accepted):

you can use this node setup:

[image]

[image]

You can now add any math node between the two multiplier nodes.

[image]

Comment: +1 but... Hehe.... the challenge is to get a stroke with even thickness.  A true (perpendicular-distance-from-sine) function is a bit of a nightmare....

Comment: I am sure you can easily do that!!!

Answer (score 10):

This aspect may not matter that much to you.. ( if it did, it might be better to go to a vector-graphics program and use its internal rasterization, or implement the graph as geometry in Blender).

As always, open to challenge, but stroking a sine-wave, or other trig. functions, with an **even thickness**, turns out to be a hard problem. See, for example, [this article](https://suricrasia.online/demoscene/sine-distance/). And you would need different distance-functions for every graphed function.

You *could* let the compositor in Blender approximate it for you with edge-detection..

First graph f(X) < Y:

[image]

And then put the result (on the left)  through edge-detection and dilation in the compositor:

[image]

but I wouldn't expect it to be worth the hack, since even that is still an approximation..

Comment: Isn’t pixel based always just an approximation….? of course +1 for this nice solution

Comment: @Chris true. But I think spline rasterisation, as in vector graphics, is a bit cleverer than _Dilate_?  Finding curve-stroking algorithms is harder than I thought.

Comment: I love watching perfectionist doing their work - but I am not one 

Comment: @Chris.. so you won't be wanting [this](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.106.5344&rep=rep1&type=pdf) :D.. lots of folks cite it. But Illustrator etc were stroking years before that.. I think it's all done by breaking down to  straight-line segments.

Comment: lol.....you are right. i am practical solution oriented....not so much interested in theoretical perfection ;) if someone is looking for perfection - my answer are all bullshit for them ;)

Comment: @Chris spoken like a true artist! :)

Comment: you won't believe it, but i don't "see" myself as an artist. Don't know why i have a problem with "artist" but i see myself as a digital creator..... ;) that's more neutral ...and art is misused to much...i think...but yeah...don't know.... ;)

Comment: @Chris As the old joke goes: 'You can tell who the real artists are... they spend the whole time talking about money'.

Comment: Loooooooooooooool

Comment: It has been [redacted] years since I taught vector graphics, but IIRC, we solved curve width problems using mean weighted dithering.  I can't find the papers now, but it doesn't really matter because you can't do that with Blender shaders anyway, AFAICT

Answer (score 5):

A really simple node setup that gives you a gradient as well, which of course can be changed to a solid line if you want.

[image]

Using a MixRGB node set to difference mode, comparing sin(x) to y just like an equation. You can do this to plot any equation, really.

[image]

Here it is with a custom color, thickness, and gradient.

Answer (score 2):

Well, I can't offer a uniform line thickness, but I ***can*** give you ***procedural axis grid lines***

[image: Math Graph - cubic]
[image: Math Graph node setup]

You can download a copy here: https://blenderartists.org/t/math-graph-shader/1380100